# attiny261 won't work when initialization is moved into a function

Tags: c, avr

**Edit:** I forgot to add an -mmcu flag during the linker step, meaning my program was not being compiled for an avr microcontroller. The code itself is correct.

I am using this piece of code to drive a seven segment display:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
  DDRA = 0xff;
  DDRB = 0xff;

  for (;;) {
    PORTA = _BV(7);
    PORTB = ~0x07;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This works fine, but when I try to set the DDRs in a helper function like this, it no longer works:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

void initIO(void)
{
  DDRA = 0xff;
  DDRB = 0xff;
}

int main(void)
{
  initIO();

  for (;;) {
    PORTA = _BV(7);
    PORTB = ~0x07;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Why is this incorrect?

This is the disassembled code:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <initIO>:
   0:   8f ef           ldi r24, 0xFF   ; 255
   2:   8a bb           out 0x1a, r24   ; 26
   4:   87 bb           out 0x17, r24   ; 23
   6:   08 95           ret

00000008 <main>:
   8:   fb df           rcall   .-10        ; 0x0 <initIO>
   a:   90 e8           ldi r25, 0x80   ; 128
   c:   88 ef           ldi r24, 0xF8   ; 248
   e:   9b bb           out 0x1b, r25   ; 27
  10:   88 bb           out 0x18, r24   ; 24
  12:   fd cf           rjmp    .-6         ; 0xe <main+0x6>
```

Comment: That doesn't sound right; post the disassembly of both `initIO()` and `main()`.

Comment: Added to the question, this has been driving me crazy for the last couple hours.

Comment: Is this the disassembly of the object file or the final binary?

Comment: There's something very wrong then; it shouldn't be starting at 0. What command line are you using to build?

Comment: `avr-gcc -Wall -Os -I/usr/avr/include -mmcu=attiny261 -o main.o -c main.`
`avr-gcc  -o voltmeter.elf main.o`

Comment: Is the disassembly result the same if you assemble directly to binary instead of using an intermediate object file?

Comment: And there's the problem, I forgot to include the -mmcu in the linker flags in my Makefile. If you leave an answer I'll upvote the crap out of it. I've been staring at a screen too long. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the device model is not specified during the final link step then avr-gcc won't generate the proper preamble required to initialize variables and to call the `main()` function. Be sure to specify the proper model at each invocation of `avr-gcc` or `avr-ld`.